# Rewrite Oracle PL/SQL procedure without merge

Tags: oracle, plsql, merge, oracle12c

I need to rewrite the below procedure without merge.
So basically the insert/update needs to be done without merge, any other alternative if possible.
Database is Oracle12c/12.1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUSH_DATA(p_id NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
MERGE INTO push_data_temp tgt
USING(
with rcte (id, data, lvl, result) 
as (
 select id, data, 1,
        regexp_substr(data,
        '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)', 1, 1, null, 1) result
   from disp_data where id=p_id
union all
 select id, data, lvl + 1,
        regexp_substr(data, '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
   from rcte
where lvl <= regexp_count(data, '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)')
 )
select *
from (
select id, lvl, replace(result,'""','') as result
from rcte
)
pivot (max(result)
FOR   (lvl) IN(1 AS col1
              ,2 AS col2
              ,3 AS col3
              ,4 AS col4
              ,5 AS col5
              ,6 AS col6
              ,7 AS col7
              ,8 AS col8
              ,9 AS col9
              ,10 AS col10
              ,11 AS col11
              ,12 AS col12))
      ) src
  ON (src.id = tgt.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
 SET col1 = src.col1
   , col2 = src.col2
   , col3 = src.col3
   , col4 = src.col4
   , col5 = src.col5
   , col6 = src.col6
   , col7 = src.col7
   , col8 = src.col8
   , col9 = src.col9
   , col10 = src.col10
   , col11 = src.col11
   , col12 = src.col12
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12)
  VALUES (src.id, src.col1, src.col2,src.col3,src.col4,src.col5,
          src.col6,src.col7,src.col8,src.col9,src.col10,src.col11,src.col12);
END;
/
```

@sujitmohanty had helped me with the procedure.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to rewrite it? What's wrong with MERGE?

Comment: Somehow its not working in actual db due to oracle version being 12.1. If i get it upgraded to 12.2 it should work and i wont be getting the upgrade before a week. So i need to rewrite and present to team using any other method asap.

Comment: It is running fine in fiddle but in actual db throwing error of inconsistent datatypes got number. The merge runs fine but when wrapped in proc throws the error

Comment: Have you tried using 11g Optimizer means alter session and downgrading the optimizer to 11g.

Comment: i am using sql developer so how should i use it and what exactly will it do?

Comment: @Vini: Please see if the updated procedure works... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6b9661071ef0c84bea325219dde6cf6....if the previous problem was with recursive with clause you probably still face the issue even without merge. If woks I will post it as answer.

Comment: The fiddle link i not working sujit

Comment: try this one...https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6b9661071ef0c84bea325219dde6cf6

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: ok,was thinking of generalizaing code a bit  but ok, thanks for the guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the procedure to use normal `loop` over `merge`. Keep in mind to change to `merge` later as it is the best option for `insert/update` operations as in your case.

I made the procedure parameter to optional, if you pass an `pid` it will do `insert/update` for the particular `pid` or else just pass null and it will do for all.

> Note: For huge data you may need to rethink on using bulk collect operation  to do the insert or update ( if only required)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PUSH_DATA(p_id NUMBER) IS
  CURSOR cur_data IS
    WITH rcte (id, data, lvl, result)
    AS (
         SELECT id, data, 1,
                regexp_substr(data,
                '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)', 1, 1, null, 1) result
           FROM disp_data where id=coalesce(p_id,id)
        UNION ALL
         SELECT id, data, lvl + 1,
                regexp_substr(data, '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)', 1, lvl + 1, null, 1)
           FROM rcte
        WHERE lvl <= regexp_count(data, '("[^"]*"|[^, "]+)')
       )
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT id, lvl, replace(result,'""','') as result
            FROM rcte)
    PIVOT (MAX(result)
     FOR (lvl) IN(1 AS col1
                  ,2 AS col2
                  ,3 AS col3
                  ,4 AS col4
                  ,5 AS col5
                  ,6 AS col6
                  ,7 AS col7
                  ,8 AS col8
                  ,9 AS col9
                  ,10 AS col10
                  ,11 AS col11
                  ,12 AS col12));
   var cur_data%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_data INTO var;
    EXIT WHEN cur_data%NOTFOUND;
    UPDATE push_data_temp
    SET col1 = var.col1
      , col2 = var.col2
      , col3 = var.col3
      , col4 = var.col4
      , col5 = var.col5
      , col6 = var.col6
      , col7 = var.col7
      , col8 = var.col8
      , col9 = var.col9
      , col10 = var.col10
      , col11 = var.col11
      , col12 = var.col12
    WHERE ID = var.id;
    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0
    THEN
       INSERT INTO push_data_temp(id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
                                  col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12)
          VALUES (var.id, var.col1, var.col2,var.col3,var.col4,var.col5,
                  var.col6,var.col7,var.col8,var.col9,var.col10,var.col11,var.col12);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Test:-*

```
BEGIN
   push_data(p_id=>null);
END;
/
```

Finally [Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0390aaac2e9ff80e23de5be668a7b6f)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220429/discussion-on-answer-by-sujitmohanty30-rewrite-oracle-pl-sql-procedure-without-m).